# Microsoft Graph is not returning full profile - but the O365 API is?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve information (ex. jobTitle, phone numbers) about users in the organisation and have tried to use the /users query but only get limited information. To be able to get the full profile I need fx. User.Read.All permission - buts this permission is for admins (or some permission from the Admin)

BUT then I found an online service which can get all informations from my organisation (without my admin have to allowed anything) using the following permissions: "Access your mailboxes", "Read and write to your contacts" and "Sign you in and read your profile".

All of these permissions cannot be achieved using the Microsoft Graph API (the exact permission text phrase is different meaning they are not using Microsoft Graph API). Why the difference ?

Do I have to use the O365 API to get the user information that I need ?

My service is going to be used in other organisations as well - so it has to work without the admin has to do anything... (like the online service that I found)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve this information for the authenticated [user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get). If you are trying to read information from *other* users within the organization however, you'll need `User.Read.All` at a minimum.

I'm not sure what service you're referencing but "Access your mailboxes", "Read and write to your contacts" and "Sign you in and read your profile" do not imply the ability to read *other* users data, only your own (the authenticated user).

- "Access your mailboxes" = `Mail.ReadWrite` or `Mail.Read`
- "Read and write to your contacts" = `Contacts.Read`
- "Sign you in and read your profile" = `User.Read`

Comment: The service I found was CiraSync.com which can sync all contacts in your organization - not only those you already have as your own contacts.

The permissions you mention result in the following permission phrases (using MS Graph) "Sign you in an read your profile", "Read your mail", "Read and write access to your mail" and "Read your contacts" which are not equal to the ones that CiraSync requires.

Comment: If you read the FAQ you will note that their Personal Edition, which only does your contacts, does not require an admin. Their Enterprise Edition requires a Global Admin. This is because it requires admin consent for those scopes. https://www.cirasync.com/faq-about-smartphone-contact-sync-ee/

Comment: Exactly. The Personal Edition does not require an admin - but it ends up adding full contact (for people not already in your contact list - GAL) information to your contact list. It must be some trick using the mail (during sync it says something like; pushing to mail...)

Comment: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/people can give me a lot more information than the Graph API can give me but not all people in my organization. CiraSync can find all people in my organization (with full profile)